# Convergence of random variables, ${X_n}^2 \xrightarrow{\text{$\mathbb{P}$}} {X}^2$

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

A sequence $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of random variables converges to $X$, so $X_n \xrightarrow{\text{$\mathbb{P}$}} X$.

Furthermore $\mathbb{E}[|X_n|] \leq 1$ for all $n$.

Show that ${X_n}^2 \xrightarrow{\text{$\mathbb{P}$}} {X}^2$.

Comment: what does it mean to say convergence of random variables? random variables for me are maps $(\Omega,P)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Comment: In order to get responses that suit your needs, please include **in the body of the question** your own thoughts, the effort made so far, and the specific difficulties that got you stuck.

Answer (score 2):

If $X_n \to X$ in probability then $f(X_n) \to f (X)$ for any continuous function  $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$. This basic fact can be proved using the fact $X_n \to X$ in probability iff every subsequence of $(X_n)$ has  a further subsequence which converges almost surely to $X$.